# Depth First Search Basics

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

I'm trying to improve my current algorithm for the 8 Queens problem, and this is the first time I'm really dealing with algorithm design/algorithms. I want to implement a depth-first search combined with a permutation of the different Y values described here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#The_eight_queens_puzzle_as_an_exercise_in_algorithm_design

I've implemented the permutation part to solve the problem, but I'm having a little trouble wrapping my mind around the depth-first search.  It is described as a way of traversing a tree/graph, but does it generate the tree graph? It seems the only way that this method would be more efficient only if the depth-first search generates the tree structure to be traversed, by implementing some logic to only generate certain parts of the tree.

So essentially, I would have to create an algorithm that generated a pruned tree of lexigraphic permutations. I know how to implement the pruning logic, but I'm just not sure how to tie it in with the permutation generator since I've been using next_permutation.

Is there any resources that could help me with the basics of depth first searches or creating lexigraphic permutations in tree form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, yes, the idea of the depth-first search is that you won't have to generate (or "visit" or "expand") every node.

In the case of the Eight Queens problem, if you place a queen such that it can attack another queen, you can abort that branch; it cannot lead to a solution.

If you were solving a variant of Eight Queens such that your goal was to find **one** solution, not all 92, then you could quit as soon as you found one.

More generally, if you were solving a less discrete problem, like finding the "best" arrangement of queens according to some measure, then you could abort a branch as soon as you knew it could not lead to a final state better than a final state you'd already found on another branch. This is related to the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

Even more generally, if you are attacking a really big problem (like chess), you may be satisfied with a solution that is not exact, so you can abort a branch that *probably* can't lead to a solution you've already found.

Answer (score 1):

The DFS algorithm itself does not generate the tree/graph. If you want to build the tree and graph, it's as simple building it as you perform the search. If you only want to find one soution, a flat LIFO data structure like a linked list will suffice for this: when you visit a new node, append it to the list. When you leave a node to backtrack in the search, pop the node off.

Answer (score 1):

A book called "Introduction to algorithms" by anany levitan has a proper explanation for your understanding. He also provided the solution to 8 queens problem just the way you desctribed it.  It will helpyou for sure.

As my understanding, for finding one solution you dont need any permutation all you need is dfs.That will lonely suffice in finding solution